# Colon after #define preprocessor directive in C?

Tags: c

Hi I am understanding a C code which has following construct, 
`#define ABD 1:0`
what does this mean? Specially what is ":" doing here in #define?

Comment: where is the define used?

Comment: It will replace all occurances of `ABD` with `1:0`. Possible use is return (a == NULL) ? ABD;

Comment: It's doing exactly what every other #define does: creating a text replacement (in this case, between ABD and 1:0).  Defines don't know nor care about syntax.

Comment: Each preprocessor directive takes up an entire line. The colon doesn't come after the directive, it's a part thereof.

Comment: It's a very useless construct, it destroys readability...

Answer (score 7):

```
int res = (n == 10)? ABD;
```

Now if `n = 10` then `res = 1` else `res= 0`

It is used in the ternary operator `?:`

So basically `ABD` is replaced by `1:0` because of the MACRO

```
#define ABD 1:0
```

Comment: Oh dear god, I really hope this is not the *actual* use case.

Comment: @sapi I'd say that `#define` is somehow "hacky" in most cases.

Comment: @sapi I too hope the same :)

Comment: @Theolodis Arguably, but this one defies all style guides and is completely unnecessary (the result of a comparison is already 0/1).

Comment: @delnan to be precise, it is `true` or `false`, but yeah, the cast is trivial ;)

Comment: @Theolodis The question is tagged C. Technically C99 has `_Bool` but the results of comparisons are still ints.

Comment: @sapi I believe `qemu` uses this in its source code (particularly for dealing with bit masking).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Yeah, [here it is](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-cris/crisv32-decode.h#l25). Although not exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

The `#define` preprocessing directives [AKA MACRO] can be considered as a *textual replacement*.

Quoting chapter 6.10 from `C99` standard, the semantics for `#define` is

```
# define identifier replacement-list new-line
```

compared to your code

```
#define ABD 1:0
```

`ABD` is the *identifier* [also called macro name], `1:0` is the *replacement list*. There is no *seperate* meaning of the `:`, other than being a part of the replacement list.

Related, chapter 6.10.3, paragraph 9,

> A preprocessing directive of the form

```
# define identifier replacement-list new-line
```

> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive.

So, if you have a MACRO like `#define ABD 1:0` and `ABD` somewhere in your code, in preprocessing stage, all occurrences of `ABD` will get replaced by `1:0`.